# Passive voice in subjunctive form

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, voz-pasiva

I was wondering if it is possible to use passive voice (both ser + past participle AND se + singular/plural 3rd person verb) in subjunctive mood?

Below is what came to my mind:

*Me gusta que todo estuviera finalizado ayer por él. - I like that everything was finalized yesterday*

*Me gusta que todo sea finalizado hoy por él - I like that everything is finished today.*

*Me gusta que todo se acabe - I like that everything is finished/will be finished*

*Me gusta que todo se acabara - I like that everything was finished.*

*Me gusta que todos los coches se vendan - I like that all the cars are sold*

*Me gusta que todos los coches se vendieran - I like that all the cars were sold*

I never encountered myself anywhere passive voice in subjunctive mood, so this question is more out of curiosity.

ALSO - if it is used in fact in subjunctive sometimes, am I correct to say that it is extremely rare case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, and no, it's not extremely rare.

There are some mistakes in your examples that are unrelated with the question. *Acabarse* is a pronominal verb, i.e. it looks like a reflexive verb but it isn't, and in your examples it's not passive voice. Also, *estar* + participle is not what we usually call "passive voice", although it is a passive construction. And *finalizado* means "ended", not "finalized", and because *finalizar* is most commonly used as intransitive, it's a bit awkward to find it in a passive construction.

But yes, there's nothing against using subjunctive mood together with passive voice. They are independent from each other. So you can say:

- *Si este árbol **fuera talado**, no tendríamos más sombra.* ("If this tree were cut down, we would have no more shade.")
- *Si **se talara** este árbol...* (same as above)
- *Una vez que **sea resuelto** el problema, hablaremos de nuevo.* ("Once the problem is solved, we will speak again.")
- *Una vez que **se resuelva** el problema...* (same as above)
- *Espero que el resultado **haya sido chequeado** cuidadosamente.* ("I expect the result has been carefully checked.")

etc.

In examples like the ones you thought up, though, one would rather use different combinations of tenses for the main verb and the subordinate verb. If you say *Me gusta que...* then you mean you like something that has **already** happened, so the subordinate should be in *pretérito perfecto compuesto*. This complicates things a bit. Using the two forms of passive voice you have:

- *Me gusta que todos los coches hayan sido vendidos.*
- *Me gusta que todos los coches se hayan vendido.*

If you want to say that **would** like something to happen you'd say *Me gustaría que...* plus a subordinate in the present tense. With passive voice this would be:

- *Me gustaría que todos los coches sean vendidos.*
- *Me gustaría que todos los coches se vendan.*

This has to do with keeping a correct temporal sequence. It isn't influenced by the choice of active or passive voice.